# Convert characters in string to integers for multiplication

Tags: c

I am having trouble getting this to work. What I want to do is take user input example `1  2  3` and then multiple each character by 2 so output would be `2  4  6`. Eventually I will take a long string of numbers and multiply every other character in the string by 2 leaving the rest untouched.

The problem I a having now is that I think it is multiplying the ASCII value by 2 not the actual integer by 2. Below is the code I have so far I haven't added any error checking to it yet to make sure the user inputs only numbers and not more than 16 etc. I am new to programming in C and am just doing this to learn.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void){


char numbers[17];
int i;
    printf("Please enter number\n");
    scanf("%s", &numbers);

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(numbers);i++){
        printf("%c\n",numbers[i] * 2);
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you think to manage 5~9 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 issues in your program

1)

```
scanf("%s", numbers);
```

2)

```
printf("%d\n",(numbers[i] - '0') * 2);
```

Here is a modfied program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char numbers[17];
    int i, len;
    printf("Please enter number\n");
    scanf("%s", numbers);

    len = strlen(numbers);

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",(numbers[i] - '0') * 2);
    }

}
```

Also, it's better to avoid `scanf` - http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: this works for integers `1-4` but `5-9` it gives me symbols I am assuming ASCII values

Comment: @Yamaha32088 - What do you want to do for 5, 6 etc. i.e. what if the input is `567` - what do you want the output to be?

Comment: I will store each integer multiplied in an array so `5>10  6>12  7>14` that is why in the original example I started a new line after every iteration through the loop so I can see the updated value

Comment: @Yamaha32088 - changed the `printf` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `atoi` function like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){


char numbers[17];
int i;
    printf("Please enter number\n");
    scanf("%s", numbers);

    for(i=0;i<strlen(numbers);i++){
        printf("%c\n", atoi(numbers[i]) * 2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work.  `atoi` accepts a char* (not a char).  I don't think it will compile without warnings.

Comment: It gave me the warnings and crashes when ran

Comment: If the OP simply wants to convert to an integer, than atoi is a good solution (no loop required).  But the OP seems to indicate that not all digits are to be doubled.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following *might* be what you are after.  It assumes `numbers[i]` contains an ASCII digit, converts it to the corresponding integer (by subtracting the ASCII value for zero), multiplies by 2 and then adds the value for ASCII zero to that result.

```
printf( "%c\n", ( numbers[i] - '0' ) * 2 + '0' );
```

That will work for characters 0 - 4.  It's not clear from my reading of the OP what is desired for digits 5-9.